# Topology of algebraic variety and Hard Lefschetz theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

I might give a (informal) talk about Lefschetz hyperplane theorem, and its original proof, which uses very concrete description of the vanishing cycles and several explicit topological manipulations to obtain the Picard-Lefschetz formula. I learned this proof from the Lamotke's article "*Topology of projective complex varieties after S. Lefschetz*".

> 1) What would be the nice examples where everything can be computed explicitely ?

(Remark : I already know the family of elliptic curves $\{y^2 = x(x-1)(x-t)\}$ which is indeed instructive, I'm looking for other examples. I didn't find much in the second book by Voisin on Hodge theory)

Also, in the article no proof of the Hard Lefschetz theorem is given, only lot of equivalent statements.

> 2) Since then, did someone found a proof of the Hard Lefschetz theorem only using Lefschetz's original approach ?

Comment: I like the notes of Nicolaescu : http://tomlr.free.fr/Math%E9matiques/Math%20Complete/Topology/Notes%20On%20The%20Topology%20Of%20Complex%20Singularities%20-%20Nicolaescu.pdf. There is a proof of Picard-Lefschetz formula and Hard Lefschetz without Hodge theorem, so this is somehow very closed to Lefschetz original approach., though it uses a lemma from Zariski which was not available in the 1920's.

Comment: @Roland : If I'm not mistaken, Nicolaescu doesn't provide a proof of Hard Lefschetz, saying that "This is a highly nontrivial result. Its complete proof requires a sophisticated analytical machinery (Hodge theory) and is beyond the scope of these lectures" (bottom of page 38). So probably it's a difficult theorem. He only proves that Hard Lefschetz is equivalent to other statement, using the same methods of Lamotke it seems. But anyway it seems a very nice complement to the notes I'm reading, so thank you !

Comment: Ah yes you are right. I used these notes several years ago for the proof of the Picard-Lefschetz formula (which is different from the one I knew : the one in SGA7), and I wrongly thought there was a proof of Hard Lefschetz.